# Applying if-else one-liner on lists in Python

Tags: python

I have an array `y` that takes a value of either 0 or 1. Then I have an array `yp` that takes values between 0 and 1. The two arrays have the same length.

If an entry in `y` is 1, then I want to append the corresponding `yp` to a list, otherwise I want to append `1-yp`:

```
y  = [1,1,1,0,0]
yp = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]

x = []
for idx, i in enumerate(y):
    if i:
        x.append(yp[idx])
    else:
        x.append(1-yp[idx])
```

Is  there a shorter way to write this in Python, perhaps without a for-loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over both lists simultaneously:

```
>>> y  = [1,1,1,0,0]
>>> yp = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
>>> [b if a else 1 - b for a, b in zip(y, yp)]
[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this if I understand you correctly?

```
for idx, i in enumerate(y):
    x.append(yp[idx]) if i else x.append(1-yp[idx])
```

More like a ternary operation approach?

Reference: http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html

Answer (score 2):

If your lists are very long, there's a more efficient way using numpy:

```py
y, yp = map(np.asarray, (y, yp)  # convert to an array
x = y * yp + (1 - y) * (1 - yp)
```

The code above, explained:

- `a = y * yp`: results in an array with the same length as `y` (and `yp`) with `1 * yp` where `y = 1` and `0` where `y = 0`.
- `b = (1 - y) * (1 - yp)`: results in an array with `1-yp` where `y=0` and `0` where `y = 1`.
- `a + b` is the pairwise sum and yields your expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for list comprehension (what you call "one-liner" ??) such as :

```
y  = [1,1,1,0,0]
yp = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
l=[yp[i] if y[i]==1 else 1-yp[i] for i in range(len(y))]
```

whill give you :

```
>>> l
[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.5]
```